# Arbitrary intersection of closed compact sets is compact (Topology)

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Arbitrary intersection of closed compact sets is compact

We've been trying to find a counter example to this, however we failed. So we would be happy if someone can tell us if this proposition is correct or false, so we can stop wasting our time trying to find a counter example

Comment: ...closed compact... Closed is superfluous. If it is compact it is closed

Comment: Your claim is true for metric spaces, but not for every topological space as far as I know

Comment: It's a closed set in a compact space, so it is compact.

Comment: @  marwalix It is true for Hausdorff spaces, but not in general.

Comment: Depends on your definition of compact: Bourbaki or not Bourbaki; for the French compact is Hausdorff and Borel Lebesgue. While the Anglo Saxon convention compact is just Borel Lebesgue. So to be precise in a Hausdorff space every subspace that verifies Borel Lebesgue is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(Y_i)$ be a family of closed compact subsets of a space $X$. The intersection of closed sets is closed. Better yet, $\bigcap_i Y_i$ is closed in $Y_j$ for each $j$ by [the usual argument for showing that a set is closed with respect to the subspace topology](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closed_Set_in_Topological_Subspace).  Since a closed subspace of compact space is compact, $\cap_i Y_i$ is compact.